# Howto hook a Guest to a `tun` Interface

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, routing, vpn, bridge

I'm trying to force all traffic from a guest (Windows or Linux) to go through the VPN of the host (Linux). To make sure that a guest has no access to the internet outside the VPN, I establish the connection on the host system, which creates a new interface `tun0`. The VPN tunnel works fine on the host.

#### Setting up `br0`, without VPN

To get internet without VPN in the guest, I create a bridge device `br0` and attach `enp7s0` to it. This way, internet works in the guest.

```
ip link add name br0 type bridge
ip link set br0 up
ip link set enp7s0 master br0
```

On the host, a `vnet5` device has been added and bridged to `br0`. But at the same time, pinging from the host to a remote does not work anymore.

```
## On the Host
sudo ip a
# ...
# 14: vnet5: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br0 state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
# link/ether ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
# inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fe92:5aa9/64 scope link
# valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
ping www.google.com
# ping: www.google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
ping 8.8.8.8
# From 192.168.1.100 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Then I start the VM with `virt-manager` and check the connection. The guest has internet:

```
## On the Guest
ip a
# 1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
# ...
# 2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
#     link/ether 52:54:00:92:5a:a9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
#     inet 192.168.1.221/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp1s0
#        valid_lft 67432sec preferred_lft 67432sec
ping www.google.ch
# PING www.google.ch (172.217.168.35) 56(84) bytes of data.
# 64 bytes from zrh04s14-in-f3.1e100.net (172.217.168.35): icmp_seq=1 ttl=117 time=2.47 ms
```

I guess instead of setting `ip link set enp7s0 master br0` I could also create routing rules between `br0` and `enp7s0`.

#### With VPN and the `tun0` Interface

When I establish a VPN connection, a `tun0` interface is created that can not be assigned to a bridge. Hence, I would need to create routing rules anyway. So I guess the situation is similar to the above case.
First, I remove `enp7s0` again from `br0`.

```
ip link set enp7s0 nomaster
sudo openvpn my_vpn_tcp.ovpn
# ...
# Initialization Sequence Completed
sudo ip a
# ...
# 3: enp7s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
# link/ether ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff permaddr ab:ab:ab:ab:ab:ab
# inet 192.168.1.100/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp7s0
# valid_lft 82702sec preferred_lft 82702sec
# ...
# 10: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 500
# link/none
# inet 10.7.7.5/24 scope global tun0
# valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
# ...
# 12: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
# link/ether 72:eb:06:e5:1e:5a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
# inet6 fe80::70eb:6ff:fee5:1e5a/64 scope link
# valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Without further do, the VPN connection is used on the host, which is OK.

```
ping www.google.com
# PING www.google.com (172.217.168.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
# 64 bytes from lala.net (172.217.168.3): icmp_seq=1 ttl=117 time=9.64 ms
# ...
ping www.google.com -I tun0
# PING www.google.com (172.217.168.3) from 10.7.7.5 tun0: 56(84) bytes of data.
# 64 bytes from lala.net (172.217.168.3): icmp_seq=2 ttl=117 time=10.0 ms
# ...
ping www.google.com -I enp7s0
# PING www.google.com (172.217.168.3) from 192.168.1.100 enp7s0: 56(84) bytes of data.
# 64 bytes from lala.net (172.217.168.3): icmp_seq=1 ttl=115 time=4.59 ms
# ...
```

But as already said, I can't add `tun0` to `br0`. And because of that, also the guest has no internet.

```
sudo ip link set tun0 master br0
# RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument
```

I searched for solutions but could not found something that works out or my case is slightly different, that would require more insight into networking that I don't have. E.g. [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/490662/how-to-route-traffic-from-br0-to-tun0-when-tun0-is-not-the-default-route-of-the) (which did not do the job) or [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/634261/how-do-i-forward-all-packets-from-wlan0-to-tun0-openvpn) (that does not exactly fit my case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two questions in the same question and they actually don't depend on each other. I'll still answer both.

Also, the `noprefixroute` address option hints a part of the network configuration is managed by some additional tool (like NetworkManager) to add routes. This answer won't attempt to deal with integration in networking tools. This is including dealing with DHCP configuration which could override later the changes if not reconfigured properly. Many settings disappear when the interface is brought down or is deleted and have to be done again, so this is best done in various hooks from various network tools in charge.

## Setting up `br0`, without VPN

An interface set as bridge port forfeits its participation in routing

Once set as a bridge port, routes associated with the interface are ignored. There might still exist harmful side effects when leaving the address on it. Details can be found in the blog [Proper isolation of a Linux bridge](https://vincent.bernat.ch/en/blog/2017-linux-bridge-isolation#bridge-processing):

> 4. hand over the frame to the device-specific *receive handler*, if any,
> 5. hand over the frame to a global or device-specific ***protocol handler* (e.g. IPv4, ARP, IPv6)**.
>
> **For a bridged interface,** the kernel has configured a device-specific
> receive handler, `br_handle_frame()`. This function won’t allow any
> additional processing in the context of the incoming interface, except
> for STP and LLDP frames, or if “brouting” is enabled. Therefore, **the
> *protocol handlers are never executed*** in this case.

The IP address set on an interface that became a bridge port should be moved to the special bridge's self interface (`br0`: the bridge itself), which is the only one able to participate in routing (there are other options but let's keep it simple). The same goes for the relevant routes.

Let's suppose OP's default gateway is 192.168.1.1/24. Let's rewrite this for the first case:

```
ip link add name br0 up type bridge
ip link set dev enp7s0 master br0

ip address flush dev enp7s0
# previous command will also have removed all associated routes as a side effect
ip address add 192.168.1.100/24 dev br0
# previous command added the LAN route too as a side effect (no noprefixroute here)
ip route add default via 192.168.1.1
```

With this, both the host and the VM can access Internet.

Note that for the VM part, `vnet5` is also a bridge port and also doesn't participate in routing. The host is just switching frames between VM and router (192.168.1.1): no routing involved.

## With VPN and the `tun0` Interface

OpenVPN relies on the TUN/TAP driver (provided on Linux by the kernel module [`tun`](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/TUN.html)). The driver can provide:

- either a layer 2 TAP interface

  It behaves like an Ethernet device and can be set as an Ethernet bridge port: that's `vnet5` created by the VM hypervisor.
- or a layer 3 TUN interface

  It doesn't include frame information (Ethernet MAC address) nor handles frames, but deals only with protocols at or above layer 3: IPv4 or IPv6. Thus it can't be set as an Ethernet bridge port. That's OP's `tun0` created by OpenVPN in TUN mode.

OpenVPN can also use TAP mode which could be bridged, but this requires to reconfigure the remote *server* side too and all the network layout: the remote server would also be part of the 192.168.1.0/24 LAN. OP doesn't appear to have control over it.

So let's consider what can be done with OP's TUN interface: this will be done at layer 3: routing, and not at layer 2.

### Reusing previous setting for trusted VMs only

If the host doesn't include advanced firewalling, including firewall restrictions and/or alterations in the bridge path, it can't force a VM to use itself as gateway: A VM bridged like previously can simply ignore the host and keep 192.168.1.1 as gateway and have its traffic not use host's `tun0` interface in the end.

If the VM can be trusted and reconfigured, one can keep `br0` as above, apply any OpenVPN setting based on `br0` (replacing any `enp7s0` reference with `br0`) and do this once the VM is running (with address 192.168.1.221) and the VPN is up:

- on host

  Using [policy/source-based routing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_routing) to select a different route outcome for this specific source:

  ```
  ip rule add from 192.168.1.221 lookup 1000
  ip rule add iif tun0 lookup 1000
  ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev br0 table 1000
  ip route add default dev tun0 table 1000
  ```

  Set as router:

  ```
  sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
  ```

And in case no such similar NAT rule already handles this case:

```
  iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.221 -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
```

- on (Linux) VM, use host as gateway instead of host's router

  ```
  ip route flush to default
  ip route add default via 192.168.1.100
  ```

### Recommended for untrusted VMs: don't set the host main interface as bridge port

This makes it easier to enforce VM's traffic through `tun0` because it won't have view of the parts of the network it should not tamper with.

- change VM settings to use its own IP network

  Example: 192.168.100.0/24 and a static IP 192.168.100.2/24 (instead of host's network DHCP), with a default gateway 192.168.100.1. On a Linux VM:

  ```
  ip address add 192.168.100.2/24 dev enp1s0
  ip route add default via 192.168.100.1
  ```
- On host, start from initial configuration (without bridging `enp7s0`)

  One could even do with zero bridge below (ie: directly `ip address add 192.168.100.1/24 dev vnet5` with `vnet5` not set as bridge port), but *libvirt* might make this more difficult.

  Just have a dedicated bridge for VMs (here using address 192.168.100.1/24, although usually *libvirt* provides a default bridge `virbr0` with 192.168.122.1/24):

  ```
  ip link add name br0 up type bridge
  ip address add 192.168.100.1/24 dev br0
  ip link set dev vnet5 master br0
  ```

  And also use [policy routing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_routing) to change the behavior of traffic related to the VM(s) for the two involved interfaces: `br0` and `tun0`. As usual it involves a few duplication and alteration of existing routes in an alternate routing table. Here `tun0` is assumed to service only the host and its VM(s). The end goal is: whatever comes from the VM side is routed to the tun side, whatever comes from the TUN side is routed to the VM side, disregarding any non-needed side.

  ```
  ip rule add iif br0 lookup 2000
  ip rule add iif tun0 lookup 2000
  ip route add 192.168.100.0/24 dev br0 table 2000
  ip route add default dev tun0 table 2000 # layer 3 interfaces don't need a gateway
  ```

  Note: incoming packets from `tun0` intended for the host (ie: not routed) are already handled by the *local* routing table and don't need any additional route in table 2000.

  Set as router:

  ```
  sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
  ```

  Then complete with NAT since the remote OpenVPN server doesn't know about 192.168.100.0/24:

  ```
  iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.100.0/24 -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
  ```

If the VM should still be able to reach the 192.168.1.0/24 LAN:

- update again table 2000 to accommodate this

  Duplicate the LAN route from main table to table 2000:

  ```
  ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev enp7s0 table 2000
  ```
- and add again an adequate MASQUERADE rule

  ... since VM is now in a different LAN that other systems don't know about:

  ```
  iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.100.0/24 -o enp7s0 -j MASQUERADE
  ```

  (Some iptables rules factorization could be done).

Comment: Thank you for your extensive and complete answer!