# How can I reach a VM through a wireguard tunnel provided by the Host?

Tags: networking, routing, wireguard

I've a working WireGuard setup with a *Server*, a *Host* and a *Machine*. The IPs are in the `10.0.0.x` range with subnet mask `255.255.255.0`. I can ping the *Machine* from the *Host* and the *Host* from the *Machine* using the WireGuard IP addresses.

[image]

Now, on the *Host* runs a virtual machine (*Guest*) that is connected to the *Host* through a bridge. I can use this excellent answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/674385/howto-hook-a-guest-to-a-tun-interface) to connect the bridge (`br0`) to the WireGuard interface (`wg0`) and route all traffic through that. The *Guest* is then able to ping to all participants but not the other way around -- **How can I reach the *Guest* from the outside? e.g. from the *Machine***.

Using the linked method, the *Guest* and the `br0` interface of the *Host* will be in a different subnet than the WireGuard network. The *Machine* has, to my limited understanding of networks, no means to find it.

I wouldn't mind putting the bridge interface and the *Guest* into the same subnet as the rest (`10.0.0.x`), but this did not work *out of the box*. In the end, I want to be able to ssh or remote-desktop into the *Guest* (which can run Linux or Windows).

Comment: It seems you need your host to perform *routing*. Please, show *all* used IP addresses, not only wireguard ones.